# Get value of datarow in c#

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding `DataRows`. I have a `DataTable` which I then converted into a list of `DataRow`'s. Now I want the string information stored in each `DataRow`. How can I do this? This is my code:

```
List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: "Now i want the string information stored in each datarow." This is a little confusing. Do you want a concatenation of all the values of a particular column? perhaps a `List<string>` or some other data collection? Maybe you want to write it out to an file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use an index to access each element. The following code would acccess the first element in the list.

```
list[0].MyString;
```

Comment: the name of the property you are trying to access.

Comment: And you can access each individual column by list[0]["columnname"], or by column index, as in list[0][0]

Comment: uh but i have no access to columns when i get a collection of rows

Comment: each datarow will maintain the schema of the datatable that it came from so you still have columns in the datarow.

Answer (score 14):

You could do this,

```
foreach(var row in list)
{
    var value = row["ColumnName"] as string;
}
```

or this to get all string values of "ColumnName" lazily.

```
var values = list.Select(row => row["ColumnName"] as string);
```

Why would you turn a DataTable into a list, though?  Just wondering.

Comment: I actually need all the contents of the datarow as list elements so i can manipulate them easier

Comment: Since the datarow will contain objects, you will have to cast all of them to a proper type afterwards and use some non-generic list (ArrayList, for example), to move DataRow contents into array. This is not necessarily the best way to do it, but it depends on your case.

Comment: List<> is a lot handier than DataTable, but if your table is huge you might be better off just using `dt` itself to avoid creating a near-duplicate data structure.  It can index just like List<> after all.  I say this having made the same mistake in the past and then running into huge data sets. List creation like this can be slow. :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.
`string t = list[row]["column name"].ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a standard indexers on DataRow:

```
string someValue =
list[0]["SomeColumn"] as string;
```

Or, if you want to work with the array of data coming from a row,

```
ArrayList lst = new ArrayList(list[INDEX_OF_THE_ROW].Count);

foreach(object value in list[INDEX_OF_THE_ROW])
{
    lst.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
    var mystring = list[0]["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method in getting a list of `DataRow` is to [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-5.0) the `DataTable`. It returns a `DataRow[]` that can easily be converted into a list.

Example of a 2 column `DataTable`:

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// TODO: Insert data into DataTable

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Select())
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(row[0].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(row[1].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve it by column name or index. So if the string you are trying to retrieve is in first column you can do list[rowNum][0].ToString()

Comment: If there is data in data table, it would be in a column. Try printing out list[0][0].ToString() and you should see it.